# How to wait with execution until the observers complete on BehaviourSubject // Angular 2 RxJS

Tags: angular, reactive, behaviorsubject

My code has a BehaviorSubject with many observers across the application.
When making a .next() on the BehaviorSubject, how can I know when all of the registered observers have completed the execution.

Comment: "completed the execution"... What do you mean ? called `.complete()` ?

Answer (score 1):

If by "completed execution" you mean "they have completed".

From the [RXJS docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) (see the little tool at the bottom of the page "Do you need to find an operator for your problem? Start by choosing an option from the list below:") :

> "I have some Observables to combine together as one Observable, and I want to be notified when all of them have completed."
>
> » You want the static operator forkJoin.

(Note that I don't know what you mean by "completed execution")

Comment: I did not mean observables have completed execution, but rather observers. BehaviourSubject has subscriptions in the code (observers as functions) that are triggered when .next event happens.

I want to know when all of the observers (functions that are subscribed to the observable) have completed the execution.

Comment: then add some code, because `forkJoin` is still the answer, but not a complete one...

Comment: thanks, will try. I was just trying to explain what I meant with "completed execution"